# Node/commonJS can "private" variable leak between requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs, koa

In an imaginary Session module as bellow, could the `_sessData` variable be leaked in between request. For instance maybe a user just logged in, and at a "same time" a isAuthed() called is made for a different user. Could this be a problem? This module would be called on every request so I guess it's safe but a confirmation would be great.

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var _sessData = null;

    function Session() {
        //
    }

    Session.prototype.set = function( payload ) {
        Cookies.set('session', payload);
        _sessData = payload;
    }

    Session.prototype.isAuthed = function() {
        return _sessData && Object.keys(_sessData).length > 0;
    }

    Session.prototype.clear = function() {
        Cookies.set('session', '');
        _sessData = {};
    }

    Object.defineProperty(app.context, 'Session', {
        // Not exaclty sure what is happening here with this and _ctx..
        // Note: apprently ctx is bound to the middleware when call()ing
        get: function() { return new Session(this); }
    });

    return function * (next) {
        var token = Cookies.get('jwt');
        if ( ! token ) {
            _sessData = {};
            return yield* next;
        }

        try {
            _sessData = jwt.verify(token, SECRET);
        } catch(e) {
            if (e.name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
                this.Session.clear();
            }
        }
        yield* next;
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

The module get used in a KoaJS app like so  (the above module does not produce a proper KoaJS middleware but this is beside the point):

```
var app = require('koa')();

// JWT session middleware
var session = require("./session")();
app.use(session);

app.listen(3080);
```

Comment: How are you calling this for each separate user/request?

Comment: @jfriend00 The actual implementation is in a KoaJS middleware. So it's used view `app.use(..)` from the bootstrap file

Comment: That doesn't explain it at all.  Is this module called separately for every new request so a new Session object is created for each request or is there only one Session object that is used by all requests.

Comment: @jfriend00 Well I guess that is the blurry part. I've update the question with some context about how this module is getting called. Does that make more sense ?

Comment: That code doesn't look like it would work.  `var session = require("./session")();` means that `session` would be an instance of a `Session` object.  So, then with `app.use(session)`, you're passing one single Session object to `app.use()` and not saving the function that creates new Session objects which makes me think that you have exactly one session object for every request which is a serious problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, looks like it is. New to node and didn't grasp that this main bootstrap file does not run on each request. I've updated the code so that it's closer to reality. Then what would you suggest ? Returning a factory that does all the logic and return a generator on each request or just reset the private variables in a the top of the generator ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're trying to do with your session code in the first place and don't know koa either.  I can see problems, but don't know the solution (which is why I haven't posted an answer).

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok. thanks for the hints tho

Answer (score 0):

What you are exporting is a function, so `_sessData` does not actually exist when you import the module. It gets created when you call the function. Each time the function is called -- and it needs to be called once per request -- a new variable in that scope with the name `_sessData` is created.  No, they cannot interfere with each other.